# How do I install & use a plugin in maven?

Tags: maven, maven-install-plugin

I would like to create a "project" with maven, when I try to install the template or whatever its called into maven it throws up an error that it needs a plugin to "install" things. I downloaded the "install" plugin from github but can't find any actual instruction where this folder should be placed nor how get maven to see & use it.

Can anyone give me a straight forward answer?

This is my first time using maven (attempting to use it anyway).
Also I am using Windows.

What I have tried:
I've searched for answers online & the "answers" I've found about this are frustratingly unhelpful and explain nothing.

What I expected to happen:
I expected to find actual intelligible instructions, written for people who don't already know how to use maven.
However,the only even remotely useful instructions I've found say to place the plugin in a folder that doesn't exist & give no clue where this folder should be created. It's almost like some big troll joke from Apache: they might as well say "to install the install plugin, install it using the install command using the install plugin installation which requires the install plugin to be installed". One answer I saw says basically "find a machine with it already installed & copy it onto the other machine".

What actually resulted:
A growing desire to print the plugin code onto paper, roll it into a tube & "install" it up the developer's butt. >:(

Comment: You do not need to install plugins manually. Show us the exact error message that you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have installed maven with this command in terminal.

---

```
mvn -v
```

---

Maven bin folder contain executable files including the 'mvn' command. Make sure this folder is in your system's PATH. If not, you need to add it yourself.

---

Maven dont require separately install plugin. It automatically downloads plugins. If you're dealing with specific plugin then specify its version in your project's pom.xml file under  section.

---

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>your-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

---

Repository Configuration:
Ensure Maven settings.xml file (found in the Maven conf directory) includes Maven Central Repository. If not, add the following within the  section:

---

```
<mirror>
 <id>central</id>
 <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
 <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

---

Make Sure you have correct project structure and pom.xml

---

Build Your Project:
Run mvn clean install in your project's directory. Maven will automatically download necessary plugins and dependencies.

---

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: I did get it to run the mvn -v thing & so I thought I had it installed properly. "Maven dont require separately install plugin. It automatically downloads plugins." Nowhere in the various "help" pages was that ever explained. That's quite obnoxious actually both the functionality & the lack of explanation.

Comment: But where do I put the plugin in manually? I followed the github link here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html & downloaded a folder there https://github.com/apache/maven-install-plugin/  that's titled "Apache Maven Install Plugin". Where is the folder supposed to go? If this isn't the plugin, then what is it?

Comment: first find the pom.xml file in your project

Comment: "specify its version in your project's pom.xml" "Make Sure you have correct project structure and pom.xml"  See now that's what I've found frustrating about this problem, almost every answer seems to assume that I have everything installed & working. But I don't! For example I don't have a project or structure started, I am trying to start my project & create a structure. It's the equivalent of asking "how do I start a car" & receiving the answer "once the car is running, just push on the gas pedal" .

Comment: then search for you plugin name for example: mongok plugin for maven and you will find your plguin or just tell me the name of plugin i will do it for you, and then add that plugin xml code in you pom.xml file in the <build></build>

Comment: ok let me start it from the begining

Comment: can you explain what code editor you are using?

Comment: I'm trying to get this mod creating template running https://github.com/CyanBlob/SpaceHavenModTemplate  but I get to the "Then, add the file with
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId="fi.bugbyte" -DartifactId=spacehaven -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile="</path/to/spacehaven.jar>" -DgeneratePom=true"  part of the instruction & maven can't do it. So you see there is no project as such. I need to get past this step. I don't think that's going to happen if a I have download a large amount of data. How big is this download?

Comment: To maybe save ourselves some time I currently have limited amount of data for downloading, if Maven is going to want to download too much data, I can't do that right now. I'll wait til I can get on a public wifi or something & can try letting maven download it's stuff & then try using again.  Thanks anyways at least I know why it wouldn't work. The program still seem very frustrating, but that's a problem for later.

Comment: Simply After clonning this project open terminal and go to project's directory and run this command But please make sure you have .jar file and add you .jar file path in this part of command------------------->  -Dfile="</path/to/spacehaven.jar>" // your .jar file path in your PC